# Hyper-V P2V Virtual Machine Bus driver

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, physical-to-virtual, scvmm

Did my first P2V experiment with SCVMM R2 - Vista 32 (Dell Precision 490) to Hyper-V on Windows Server 2008.  I'm having issues with "integration Services" and "virtual machine bus" driver.

When I install Integration Services it claims to install successfully, but clicking the mouse on the screen still says I need to install Integration Services.

When I try to install a virtual machine bus driver I get "Windows cannot load the device driver for this hardware. The driver may be currupted or missing. (Code 39)"

The VM doesn't see the virtual network card, and I'm assuming this is related to the virtual machine bus.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Code 39 in Device Manager generally means that there's some function that the driver is trying to invoke which doesn't exist in the NT kernel.  (Unless the images is in fact corrupt, which probably isn't the case here.)  In this situation, that probably implies that VMBus is trying to use something that is missing.  This could happen if your guest OS doesn't have all the service packs installed.  If I remember correctly, Vista needed at least one patch to be supported.

In order to install the patches, you can either mount your VHD file and use the Vista offline patching mechanism or you can install a "legacy network adapter" in the VM and download the patches from Windows Update.

Comment: Patches aren't the problem here.  The machine was fully patched.  But thanks for the 'legacy network adapter' tip - I was able to run Windows update and confirm that the patches are all done.